# XMLHttpRequest behaving differently in Chrome 19 -- 'faking' requests?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Here is some example code.  Successively make four xmlhttprequests()s to the same url.  In this case, I expect four requests to go on the wire, with four different responses, since in this case, the URL returns a new UUID on each call.  In Chrome 18, Firefox, and Safari, this is what happens.

In Chrome 19, however, only one request goes on the wire, but the browser acts as if all four requests returned with the same value.  That is, the callback is executed four times, but with the same response text each time.  Developer Tools and Wireshark both confirm that only one request was actually made.

I thought it might have to do with browser caching behavior, but playing with both client-side (pragma: no-cache) and server-side (Cache-Control: no-cache) didn't help.  Adding a bogus query parameter that is different for each request does force it do make all four actual requests, but I'm still curious what changed and what another way to deal with it might be (other than URL parameters).  I also suspect I'm doing something weird or wrong, since I'm unable to find other people talking about this.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<script>
  function doOne(i) {
    var xh =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xh.open("GET", "/uuid", true);
    xh.setRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
    xh.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xh.readyState == 4) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = xh.responseText;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    }
    xh.send(null);
  }
  window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      doOne(i);
    }
  }
</script>
```

For reference, here is what I'm using for the example server for this test case (web.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import uuid
import web

urls = (
  '/uuid', 'Uuid',
)

class Uuid():
  def GET(self):
    web.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    return str(uuid.uuid1())

app = web.application(urls, globals())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

Comment: Try to send all next response (server) header for _"no caching"_. `Cache-Control: no-cache`, `Date: GMT current time here` _(for example, Date: Thu, 17 May 2012 05:44:24 GMT)_, `Expires: -1`, `Pragma: no-cache`

Comment: @AndrewD. Thanks for the comment; pragma: no-cache is for requests, not responses, and in the example code, I am setting it on the request.  For Cache-Control, I also tried no-store, which did not help.

Comment: `pragma` can be used in both: request and response. Also you can simply check it: find something on google, then check in FF firebug or Chrome DevTools on network tab. Seek for responses with `Cache-Control:no-cache`. In all responses with `Cache-Control:no-cache` you can see `Pragma:no-cache` also.

Comment: @AndrewD. Sure, sites like Google that want to work with all sorts of quirky and/or ancient clients may set it, but the RFC is clear that it's to be used on requests.  In my case, my question is specific to the days-old version of a very modern browser developed by Google itself, so it's very reasonable to assume it understands Cache-Control and doesn't rely exclusively on an old misinterpretation of Pragma:.  Anyway, just to make you happy, I did try it; it has no effect :)  Thank you again for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same issue using Chrome 19 within my Rails application. To fix it this code works fine for me:

```
before_filter :set_cache_buster
def set_cache_buster
  if request.xhr?
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
end
```

It disables caching for every XMLHttpRequest.

Credits: http://blog.serendeputy.com/posts/how-to-prevent-browsers-from-caching-a-page-in-rails/

Comment: Ugh the commenting system here.  Apologies for the mess above.  The main point is I tried the set of headers you had, confirmed that they were being put on the wire as expected, but they do not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Recently stumbled upon this also and haven't found a good way of forcing Chrome to not reuse the response. Firefox does not seem to have this behaviour.

I've filed an [chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333804) and hope someone can make it clear if this is intended behaviour or a bug.

Comment: The issue was partially fixed in Chrome 34 and fully fixed in Chrome 35.  Unfortunately, Android 4.4's WebView is Chrome 33 and still suffers from the issue. Updates to the Chrome browser app do not also update the copy used by other apps that embed WebView GUI components, so these apps are stuck on Chrome 33.  This will affect Android developers that still support Android 4, so it's advisable to call `browser.clearCache()` from time to time if `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK` is 19 (or possibly below; I don't know if anybody checked which was the *first* version of Chrome to have this problem).